# Can I bind an unprivileged application to privileged port on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, security, tcp, osx-snow-leopard, communication

I am writing a server type application which is normally run by a user but needs to bind to a privileged TCP port (502 - Modbus TCP). The port number is industry standard and my app is a simulator, so I can't really change to >1024 as most devices are pre-programmed for this port number and can not be changed.

The "Root EUID Security Policy" protects port 502 from access by anyone but root (see [Authentication, Authorization, and Permissions Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Conceptual/AuthenticationAndAuthorizationGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)  ). Therefore, the call to CFSocketSetAddress fails when using ports < 1024.

I'm trying to avoid running my simulator app as root for obvious security reasons.
Sandboxing may overcome this problem but I understand it's only available in 10.7 Lion and I have to work in 10.6 SL.

Could someone please point out what would be considered "best practice" for port access in this instance and maybe some pointers to examples and further reading.

Many Thanks

PS: I have seen Apple's [Better Authorization Sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/BetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html) but it is 5 years old and a bit cumbersome involving a privileged helper tool run by launchd. I'm hoping there is a better solution that doesn't involve running a process as root.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this with `ipfw`; try [here](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/firewalls-ipfw.html)  to learn about it and `man ipfw` for more details.

Comment: sorry, my initial question didn't make it clear that I'm writing a coca application and need to bind to the port from within my app. I have edited my original question to reflect this.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the way Apache's https starts… it starts as root long enough to grab port 80 / 443, and then runs as an 'apache' or 'http' user from then on.